# Serverless-framework postgresql version upgrading problem

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

We use serverless-framework and Postgresql.

```
Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
Properties:
  EngineVersion: 11.8
```

It was 11.8 before, we successfully upgraded it from 11.8 to 11.9 by changing the version in `serverless.yml` in `EngineVersion`.
But now we need to upgrade it to 11.10 and we have the following issue:

The error message:

```
Cannot upgrade postgres from 11.9 to 11.1 (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: e0d1923a-cf98-44ea-a9e4-bc3871e33bf6; Proxy: null).
```

So it looks like it tries to upgrade to 11.1 rather than 11.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `11.10` value you're specifying for the `EngineVersion` property is processed as a number by the YAML engine since you're not using quotes, so the trailing zeros are removed and the resulting value is `11.1`. You need to specify the value in quotes, like this: `"11.10"`

Answer (score 3):

It seems like Serverless ignores '0' in Engine Version that you are trying to set up.
Could you try to escape version with quotes?

It will look like this:

```
Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
Properties:
  EngineVersion: '11.10'
```

It should help to solve the problem and upgrade version successfully